# Add timestamp to generated document

Tags: compiling

Is it possible to add timestamp to the pdf file generated from the latex or lyx file ? To clarify, let us assume we have a file named demo.tex . When we compile , it should compile a pdf labelled demo141019.pdf . Can this be done using xetex with a code in preamble?

Comment: It can be done with `latexmk`. Don't know if inside LaTeX can be done.

Comment: As soon as `pdftex` starts, it sets the name of the output PDF file. If we launch it with the option `-jobname=<newname>`, then the variable containing the output name will use `<newname>` instead of the file name. I don't know whether it's possible to do this with LyX (probably not, I'm afraid).

Comment: @m0nhaw kindly explain how can we do it with latexmk, or arara